# How can I find the missing parameters in a C# function call?

Tags: c#, function, named-parameters

When a named parameter in a C# function is missing, the compiler only prints the number of arguments that are missing instead of printing the name of each missing parameter in the function:

```
prog.cs(10,27): error CS1501: No overload for method `createPrism' takes `2' arguments`.
```

However, for debugging purposes, it is often necessary to obtain the names of the parameters that are missing in a function call, especially for functions that take many parameters. Is it possible to print the missing parameters in a C# function call?

```
using System;
public class Test{
    public static int createPrism(int width, int height, int length, int red, int green, int blue, int alpha){
        //This function should print the names of the missing parameters
        //to the error console if any of its parameters are missing. 

        return length*width*height;
    }
    static void Main(){
        Console.WriteLine(getVolume(length: 3, width: 3));
        //I haven't figured out how to obtain the names of the missing parameters in this function call.
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a compile-time error. What kind of code do you expect to be able to run before it's compiled? Unless you're writing a compiler, I don't see how this is possible.

Comment: @p.s.w.g See the answer below: someone figured out how to do this using default parameter values!

Comment: @AndersonGreen That doesn't answer the question asked. While default values are nifty, it's an orthogonal topic entirely. It simply allows one to omit arguments (and have the defaults filled in) - nifty, but it doesn't address a mismatched signature.

Comment: Consider refactoring to have sane number of arguments (1-3?)... If you function would not take 7 arguments you'd not have problem figure out which one is passed as default...

Comment: @user2246674 The function can throw an error when any of the parameters are set to null by default, so it actually is a working solution. See [Alex's solution below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17414740/975097). If the function is designed this way, then it will throw an error whenever a parameter is missing, which is exactly what I want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can make all parameters nullable and set them a default value. Then, in your method you can check what parameters have null value and do something about it.

```
   public static int createPrism(int? width=null, int? height=null){
       if(!height.HasValue){
         Console.Write("height parameter not set")
       }
   }
```

Comment: This looks like a useful solution. Would it be possible to do this without using a separate if-statement for each parameter?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do when paramter not set. You can wrap this check into some method that accepts object and checks if it is null. Generally, if you just want to have different set of parameters, you might as well create several overloads of your method, each accepting the needed set of parameters.

Comment: @AndersonGreen - essentially no - there is no concept of "list of arguments" inside method call. You can proxy calls and automatically build methods to check each individual argument - will give you some Code.Emit fun...

Comment: In this case, perhaps it would be better to throw an exception than to write a message to the console.

Comment: While that solution may be ingenious, it also means writing highly unsafe code for a little debugging comfort. I would strongly advise against using anything like this except for ad-hoc debugging. Meaning: Put it in, do your debugging, then immediately change it back again.

Answer (score 1):

The only think I can think of that comes close is using optional parameters:

```
public static int createPrism(int width = -1, int height = -1, int length = -1, int red = -1, int green = -1, int blue = -1, int alpha = -1){
    if(width == -1)
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid parameter 'width'");
    if(height == -1)
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid parameter 'height'");
    ...

    return length*width*height;
}
```

This will print out the correct result in the case of:

```
createPrism(length: 3, width: 3);
```

However, there's nothing to prevent a user from writing something like this:

```
createPrism(width: -1, height: -1);
```

<sub>*alex*'s answer is another form of this that works equally well. The trick is to ensure that the default value is one that's not an valid parameter value.</sub>

---

Another technique would be to use a dictionary of parameters

```
public static int createPrism(Dictionary<string, int> parameters){
    if(!parameters.ContainsKey("width"))
        Console.WriteLine("Missing parameter 'width'");
    if(!parameters.ContainsKey("height"))
        Console.WriteLine("Missing parameter 'height'");
    ...

    return parameters["length"] * parameters["width"] * parameters["height"];
}
```

But calling this becomes very cumbersome:

```
createPrism(new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "length", 3 }, { "width", 3 } });
```

You can overcome this to some degree using a `dynamic` parameter type:

```
public static int createPrism(dynamic parameters){
    if(parameters.GetType().GetProperty("width") == null)
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid parameter 'width'");
    if(parameters.GetType().GetProperty("height") == null)
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid parameter 'height'");
    ...

    return parameters.length * parameters.width * parameters.height;
}
```

Which becomes:

```
createPrism(new { length: 3, width: 3 });
```

---

Though ultimately, the best option is simply to let the compiler do it's job. Your original declaration is sufficient to ensure that the calling code has provided all necessary parameters for your function to return successfully. In general, if the function can execute without a given parameter, it should be made optional (either through a default value or with an overload that omits it), and the compiler will take care of the rest. All you should worry about is whether the *value* provided by the caller is valid.